# Always run program with admin rights

Tags: windows

Ive developed a small piece of software that runs on Windows for a client. After the dev was complete i learned that the machines it will run on wont have admin rights. Are there any options to be able to run the software with admin rights?

The program will be used on lots of machines so it would be good if it included as few steps as possible. I guess its possible to ask the client have someone with admin rights install the program. Maybe then it can be set to always run with admin rights?

Comment: Anything you do as an author of a program, to make it always run with elevated permissions, still requires the user to be able your process to those elevate those permissions.  Simple Said: **You can indeed make your program always run with those permissions but the user still must be an Administrator.**  There are literally dozens of questions on that topic.

Comment: So there is no way to make it so that a non administrator can run the software with administrator privilegies?

Comment: That is indeed correct. Any method to escalate the process would requires  a user, it doesn't have to be the same user who stated the process, to escalate the permissions of the process.

Comment: @Lautaro, when the software is run as a user, it is limited to that users privledges, with no exception. Windows recommends that whenever a user application should perform tasks that require administrative priv, that the software be separated into two components, a user interface, and a service. The service runs under a system service user account (like localservice, networkservice, localsystem, etc), and the user interface can be run under the logged in users credentials.

Comment: Thanks everyone! 
@Frank Thomas: Ok so if i rewrite the software to run as a service instead, does it need the admin to set it up?

Comment: yes, but only to set up.

Comment: Thank you! Do you want to make your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the run up to windows Vista, and the introduction of UAC, Microsoft changed the way administrator rights are provided to users and applications, and many applications had to change their architecture to accommodate the new rules.

Microsoft provided this document, with several differant strategies for dealing with these changes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756990.aspx

Many of the options involved dividing the binary up into multiple executables, so that they can be run separately with different levels of privilege and user configurations.

In your case, the option entitled "The Back-End Service Model" in the document above is the most appropriate for the solution you have described. It involves separating out functionality that requires administrative privileges, and placing it in a windows Service, which can be configured to run as a privileged user without requiring interactive invocation from the user.